# How to determine current as a function of time in an RLC circuit with variative capacitor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance, spring

I was given this problem:

[image: Circuit Problem]

The image shows an RLC circuit which consist of a constant voltage source $\varepsilon$, an inductor with inductance of $L$, a resistor with resistance of $R$, and a capacitor, which consist of two conductor plates and one of the plate (with mass $m$ may move freely. Both plates are connected with two springs with constant of $k$. It is known that the freely-move-plate is applied with an external force of $p(t)$, with $$ p(t) = p_0 \sin(\omega t) $$ When the spring is in equilibrium, the capacitor have capacitance of $C_0$ and the spring has length of [image: length-eq]. I was asked to determine the current in the circuit as a function of time $L(t)$.

So the first thing that I had in mind is to find the function of distance between the capacitor plates as a function of time ($d(t)$).

In this case, the external force is opposed by spring force of the two spring. Therefore,
$$ p(t) = -2kx(t) $$
$$ p_0 \sin(\omega t) = -2kx(t) $$
$$ x(t) = -\frac{p_0}{2k} \sin(\omega t) $$

Thus, the distance between the two plates is
$$ d(t) = a -\frac{p_0}{2k} \sin(\omega t) $$

We know that the capacitance between two parallel plates is
$$ C = \frac{\varepsilon_0 A}{d} $$
therefore,
$$ C(t) = \frac{\varepsilon_0 A}{a -\frac{p_0}{2k} \sin(\omega t)} $$

At equilibrium position, we know that
$$ C = C_0 = \frac{\varepsilon_0 A}{a} $$
$$ \varepsilon_0 A = C_0 a $$

Thus, we'll get the capacitance as a function of time,
$$ C(t) = C_0 \frac{a}{a -\frac{p_0}{2k} \sin(\omega t)} $$

After I get this function, I tried to apply it to a function related to the circuit. The total voltage between inductor, resistor, and the capacitor is
$$ V_L + V_R + V_C = \varepsilon $$
$$ L \frac{d^{2}q}{dt^2} + R \frac{dq}{dt} + \frac{1}{C} q = \varepsilon $$
$$ L \frac{d^{2}q}{dt^2} + R \frac{dq}{dt} + \frac{1}{C_0} \frac{a -\frac{p_0}{2k} \sin(\omega t)}{a} q = \varepsilon $$
My hunch told me to find the function of $q(t)$ from this equation, and determine the first derivative as $I(t)$. But, after I tried methods to find a solution for a second-order differential equation, I can't find the right way. There is another function of time as the coefficient of $q$ in the equation. I think I haven't studied that far.

So, is my work here "on-point"? Am I getting closer to find the solution or just wandering off indistinctly?

Comment: I'm thinking you need a switch in the circuit which is closed at t = 0. Then any oscillations will be damped by the resistor. The harmonic oscillations of the capacitor are likely to be forced at the same frequency as the (transient) oscillations of the LC circuit.

Comment: Shouldn't you have something like $m \ddot{x} = p(t) - k x$ instead?

Comment: @R.W.Bird Yeah, I think that's what the problem meant. All activities in the circuit start at $t = 0$. But I haven't read about transient oscillations. I think I skipped that part in lecture.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert So the external force does not acted as the spring force, but instead resulting in a net force with the spring force? I think I still haven't got the idea of that. I think I need to read more.

Comment: I was wrong about the switch. I did not get clear on the idea that the capacitor plate was driven by an external force. Given that, there will be a steady state (forced and damped) oscillation in the circuit at  the frequency of the external force.